# T-SQL query not grouping results in output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the follwoing query embedded in a stored procedure

```
select u.UserName, s.Name, count(i.id) as NumberAccounts, sum(i.total) as CCTotal
  from invoice i 
    inner join visit v on v.id = i.id
    inner join branch b on b.id = v.branchid
    inner join practice p on p.id = b.practiceid
    inner join visitscheme vs on vs.id = v.id
    inner join [plan] pl on pl.id = vs.planid
    inner join scheme s on s.id = pl.schemeid
    inner join creditcontrol cc on cc.SchemeId = s.id
    inner join [user] u on u.id = cc.userid
 where p.APIKey = @pracId
   and (u.id = @CCid OR @CCId = '999999')
   and (s.id = @SchemeId or @SchemeId = 999999)
 group by u.UserName, s.Name
 order by u.username
```

When I run it instead of result being grouped by username and scheme I get the following

```
UserName    Name    NumberAccounts  CCTotal
chanel   BANKMED    9954            11882514.19
ciske    BANKMED    9954            11882514.19
Estee    BANKMED    9954            11882514.19
Feroza   BANKMED    9954            11882514.19
```

No grouping applied, the same values in each.  Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `inner join visit v on v.id = i.id` or some similar join is wrong?

Comment: Impossible to tell without a good knowledge of your tables/business logic but at first I see a lot of redundant joins. Tip: Try to rewrite it adding one join at a time and only if it's absolut necessary.

Comment: The issue is that the amounts are not being grouped.  the result set is correct, but instead of different values on each user the same values are repeated- in other words the grouping is being ignored

Comment: Outcome is correct since your code returns values aggregated based on two columns with "group by u.UserName, s.Name" . Query output has distinct combinations of UserName and Name (s.Name)

Comment: @jean Every join is there as it is needed due to the db structure.  wish there were redundant joins but sadly they are all needed

Comment: @eralper  The output is wrong- the aggregate is for all the values combined- no grouping has been applied i.e. the uniqu values for each group of username and name are not appearing

Comment: It is grouping correct (never seen SQL group incorrectly). Your join is likely not guaranteeing a single invoice is associated with a single user. No way to really tell as we don't know your system, nor have a reproducible minimal verifiable example. The invoice doesn't have a direct link to a user?

Comment: Your grouping is not being ignored. You have a logical error in your code or your structures are not well designed. Please provide table details and enough data to reproduce the issue and we can help.

Comment: Again: There's something in your joins wrong making it to fetch all invoicers from all users. Try it: remove the where caluse and the branch and practice joins, see if it helps to fetch things grouped. Keep following this tatic until you find the wrong join(s)

Comment: Isn't your query supposed to return 1 row, that for `u.id = @CCid`? And that one row can easily by duplicated into 4 by an incorrect join.

Comment: Found the problem- the user was not restricted by ractice- so multiple users were being returned instead of one...  Too few limits in the where!  Good spit Salman, thanks

Comment: A query/join pattern that complicated is a good use case for a view

Comment: If your joins are correct, then `invoice.id` = `visitscheme.id`. Are you sure? At least `branch` and `practice` aren't needed.

Comment: This is just a suspicion, but an educated guess would be that `inner join practice p on p.id = b.practiceid
    inner join visitscheme vs on vs.id = v.id` - v.Id should be some other column.

Comment: One of the things you are struggling with here is one of my biggest pet peeves. Using Id as a column name. It is ambiguous and causes all sorts of problems. A PlanID is always a PlanID no matter what table it is in. Columns changing names between tables is painful to work with and can cause joins to inadvertently be made incorrectly. That could be what is going on here.

Comment: It seems to be doing the right thing.  What do you mean by "No grouping applied"?

Answer (score 0):

just write like this....

```
select u.UserName, s.Name, count(i.id) as NumberAccounts, sum(i.total) as CCTotal
  from invoice i 
    inner join visit v on v.id = i.id
    inner join branch b on b.id = v.branchid
    inner join practice p on p.id = b.practiceid and p.APIKey = @pracId
    inner join visitscheme vs on vs.id = v.id
    inner join [plan] pl on pl.id = vs.planid
    inner join scheme s on s.id = pl.schemeid and (s.id = @SchemeId or @SchemeId = 999999)
    inner join creditcontrol cc on cc.SchemeId = s.id
    inner join [user] u on u.id = cc.userid and (u.id = @CCid OR @CCId = '999999')
 group by u.UserName, s.Name
 order by u.username
```

assuming that your joins are correct